# How do I implement an automatic dependency check before every gradle build?

Tags: gradle, dependencies, dependency-management

I've found plenty of options to check for dependencies manually. My goal is to automatically check for dependency updates before gradle builds the project. Is there any way to execute gradle tasks in the gradle build script? Or any other way to check for dependency updates automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is to use task dependencies ( `dependsOn` ) to automate the tasks